# How to raise pavers by 3 to 5 inches from rest of flat lawn for shed base?

Tags: pavers, foundation

I am installing a Resin based shed [Ketter Cortina 9x7](https://www.keter.com/ca_en/msdl_17204256artisan-9x7-shed.html)in my backyard on level ground. I want to build the shed base using 24x30 inch [concrete paver slabs](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/oldcastle-24x30-diamond-slab-natural/1000402078). to build the base I am planning to.

- remove the grass and dig a 4 inches
- lay a weed control sheet
- add gravel
- compact it
- put the pavers on the gravel.
- assemble the shed on the pavers

The issue with my plan is that the pavers are only 2 inches thick and I want the shed to be about 5 inches off the ground. How can I raise the ground under the pavers by 3 to 5 inches so that my shed will be higher than the rest of the lawn?

I thought about putting a some pressure treated wood 4x4 perimeter to contain gravel and raise it 4 inches above the rest of the lawn then put the paver salbs on to raised gravel bed. However, I am concerned about wood rotting after a few years and having to spend time fixing the base.

I don't have any landscaping experience this my first DYI backyard project, so I am looking for simple approaches. I have thought of two ways to do this but I have not seen anyone else online mention these so they probably don't work.

- Put two pavers on top of each other
- dig a 6 inch deep, 10 inch wide perimeter trench, put 2 inches of gravel in it, then place an [8x16x8 cinder block](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/oldcastle-10-inch-block-natural/1000149960) and fill the shallow trench with gravel. the cinder blocks will stick 4 inches above the ground and form a perimeter so I can fill the inside with gravel, then put the pavers on top of the gravel.

Can the above two approaches work, what are the downsides of each approach, is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: You don't need landscape fabric ("weed control sheet") under pavers if you use 3-6" of compacted base gravel, especially with a building on top of the pavers. Landscape fabric does nothing to deter weeds over the long term anyway, even in a garden.

Comment: Why do you need the shed base to be higher than the lawn? Are you putting in some slabs around the shed, particularly where the door is?

Comment: Just want to keep water out if we get a big rainfall and when the snow melts.

Comment: ground-contact rated PT lumber shouldn't rot out in a few years...

Answer (score 1):

That should work but a lot of work. I would just put something like sand on the grass, then the paver slabs , then the shed. What I did for my 8 X 12 shed is rake the sandy soil and weeds flat and set house bricks on the ground to make a porous floor . I have aquariums in the shed and occasionally run gallons of water on the "floor" , it just disappears. It has worked for 20 years, never a weed. Although I never get freeze/thaw in the shed. We did have a 40 inch rain (3 days) which was no problem.

Comment: My own shed had a similar construction method, except that the owners used about 6" of base gravel piled on the grass. The shed came with its own floor, however.